# how to get data from External API url

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

I am using `laravel v5.8.17` and i got this code from this side somewhere but my code is not working properly , i can only get status code `200` but cannot be return the response (body and header) , I tried like this : (at controller)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class yourController extends Controller
{
    public function saveApiData(){

    if(isset($_res['https://my_api_url'])){
            require './vendor/autoload.php';  

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://my_api_url', [
            'formData' => [

             'email' => 'myemail',
             'password' => 'mypassword',            

    ] ]);

        echo $res->getStatusCode();
        //200

        echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
        //'application/json; charset=utf8'

        echo $res->getBody();
        // "type":"User"...'    

    }   

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make it like this:

```
print_r(json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()));exit(0);
```

Comment: please can you check it as right answer @RockyYOKOHAMA